# Mercurial: How do I find the most recent revision that includes a specific file, if possible?

Tags: linux, mercurial

I have a file that's been modified recently. Rather than looking into each revision, is there an easier way to find out, in Mercurial, in which revision the file was last modified? Thanks.

Note that I am using command line in Linux.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will give you the last time a change was made to a particular file (increase 1 to N to see last N changes):

`hg log -l 1 ./path/to/file`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just gave it a try but the result is kinda weird. It could be my misunderstanding or a bug. Basically, I ran `hg log -l 1 foo.py` and it responded with revision 141. With the rev#, I ran `hg status --rev 141`, which returned the list of affected files in this commit, but foo.py was not in the list. To verify that further, I diffed the current copy of foo.py with rev# 141 and there was no differences. Could you think of anything that might have caused this contracting result?

Comment: `hg status --rev X` doesn't tell you what changed *in* revision X, but what the status of the current working copy is *compared to* revision X. To see the changes in revision X you could do `hg status --change 141`

Comment: Oh~~I have been misunderstood that command. Thanks for clarifying that and pointing out the right command for me. You made my day :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer of Autopulated is exactly what you are looking for if you just want to have a look on the last revision for a file.

I just wanted to mention the `grep` command :

```
$ hg help grep
hg grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...

search for a pattern in specified files and revisions
[...]
```

With `hg grep`, you can search a particular file or the whole repository at any revision or range of revision for a particular pattern.

It is the kind of command which is really helpful if you're searching for the revision in which a particular method or variable was introduced or removed for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this tip, krtek. Much appreciated! I can already think of many scenarios in which `hg grep` could be helpful.